# SharePoint 2016, 500 Internal server error

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, internal-server-error

Today when I checked my SharePoint 2016 on premise it gives me

> 500 Internal server error ,

I checked the Application Pool (All the application are running correctly), I restarted IIS also but still I am getting the same error.

C.A is working fine

Comment: Did you check your SQL Server service is running? If C.A. is working fine, You should take a look at your ULS logs.

Comment: I checked that and tried all solution which is present in the Internet(Google), But issue is still there. and  i find one more thing is that when i create a new web application with a new site collection , While trying to access that also giving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the solution for my problem.

Here I am giving the steps that I have done:

1. Go to SharePoint Management Shell( ISE ) (Run as administrator) and run the Below powershell command:

   ```
   Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
   $hostConfig = Get-SPServiceHostconfig
   $hostConfig.Provision()
   $SPservice = Get-SPServiceApplication |?{$_.name -eq 'SecurityTokenServiceApplication'}
   $SPservice.Provision();

   Import-Module WebAdministration
   Stop-Website 'SharePoint Web Services'

   Start-Website 'SharePoint Web Services'
   ```

Comment: I faced this issue in sharePoint 2016 On -Premise server, because During  installation System Admin provided me with two Administrator for server. this  cause Following:-  (1)  Service and Application Pool is started /created by one admin  and  when another admin trying to use it in his site Collection, that is not working correctly .for example Profile Service synchronization causes problem.                          Thank You !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the web service url of SharePoint webservices to 16 hive, in my case it point to 15 hive folder.
https://abdulazizfarooqi.wordpress.com/2016/04/30/sharepoint-2016-http-500-internal-server-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-site-using-claims-based/